# Summing an Array with random values

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, sum

I need to make a function that sums my array, which is filled with random values. My function only returns 0 and not an actual summation of the array. I don't have much experience with arrays or random values, how can I code my `arrSum` function to give me the sum of the array when called?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 1000

int arrSum(int arr[SIZE], int b) {
    if (b < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return arr[b] + arrSum(arr, b - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int inputNum;
    int i;
    int arr1[SIZE];
    int sum;
    srand(time(0));

    printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 1000: ");
    scanf("%d", &inputNum);

    sum = arrSum(arr1, inputNum);
    printf("sum: %6d\n\n", sum );

    printf(" Pos   |  Val\n");
    printf("-------------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < inputNum; i++) {
        printf("%4d   |%4d\n", i, rand() % 1001);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (arr < 0)` What do you think this does? Does your compiler complain when you compile with warnings on?

Comment: Does this compile with all the warnings on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is initially there are no values in the array. But only 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 1000
int arrSum(int arr[SIZE], int b){
  if (b < 0) return 0;
 else return arr[b] + arrSum(arr, b-1);
}
 int main(){
  int inputNum;
  int i,q;
  int arr1[SIZE] = {0};
  int sum;
  srand(time(0));

   printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 1000: ");
   scanf("%d",&inputNum);

   for(q=0;q<inputNum;q++){
     arr1[q] = rand() % 1001;
    }

    sum = arrSum(arr1, inputNum);
    printf("sum: %6d\n\n", sum );

    printf(" Pos   |  Val\n");
    printf("-------------\n");
  for (i = 0; i < inputNum; i++){
   printf("%4d   |%4d\n", i,arr1[i]);
 }
  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind finding the sum inside the function is correct, assuming that `b` is within the range of the array indices. The real problem is that your array is *not* filled with random numbers - it is filled with zeros.

When you do

```
int arr1[SIZE] = {0};
```

you are initializing each element to `0`, and are not changing it at any point during the program. So, your function returns the sum from indices `0` to `b`, but this turns out to be `0`.